# Determining modules loaded once program starts

Tags: perl, module, perl-module

I have a forking server. I load all modules before I fork.

...or do I? I want a message to be logged to STDERR for every module loaded after a certain point in my program.

I was going to use the following, but it's logging some scripts executed using `do`.

```
my %ignore = map { $_ => 1 } ( ... );
unshift @INC, sub {
   my (undef, $path) = @_;
   warn("$path wasn't loaded before forking.\n")
      if !$ignore{$path};

   return ();
};
```

I'm not out of ideas, but before I spend more time on this, I was wondering if there's an existing solution.

Comment: I could write a solution that dumps `%INC` on exit, but I'd rather avoid that since this is a long-lived process that only exits by signal.

Comment: `%ignore` is there because some modules attempt to load others to determine if they are installed.

Comment: Do you control the forking in your own Perl code, or is the fork part of some other beast that you just plug into?

Comment: If you know about the ones that are `do`ne, why don't you just pot those in `%ignore`?

Comment: @Len Jaffe, I have some control. Assume it's all my code.

Comment: Btw I think you wanted to say `unless $ignore{$path}`. With the `if` it only `warn`s for the ones it should ignore.

Comment: @simbabque, That might be the simplest. I'd have to introduce regex, though. Perl builtins alone load a number of files using `do`. Honestly, I wish I didn't have to use `%ignore` at all.

Comment: If you control the forking, dump %INC before the fork, and then dump %INC in the child, later, and compare...

Comment: @Len Jaffe, See the first comment...

Comment: But you're trying to determine the program's run-time profile.  You do it once or twice, collect a bunch of logs to analyze, and then you stop doing it.  Combine that with some static analysis to pre-compute all of your includes and their dependencies.

Comment: @Len Jaffe, Can't do it "once or twice". The load could happen at any time in its "infinitely" long lifetime. And I really hate the idea of buffering/postponing error logging.

Comment: sure you can. keep a counter... only dump INC on the when counter < X.

Comment: @Len Jaffe, Let me rephrase: I don't want to do it just once or twice. The load could happen at any time in the program's "infinitely" long lifetime, so you're effectively suggesting what I've already said I don't want to do: Waiting until the process exits. That's not really safe here, and generally speaking, I really hate the idea of buffering/postponing error logging. In short, see my first comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
my $old_require =
   defined(&CORE::GLOBAL::require)
      ? \&CORE::GLOBAL::require
      : sub { CORE::require($_[0]) };

my $new_require = sub {
   my $path = shift;
   if ($INC{$path}) {
      return $old_require->($path);
   }

   my $rv = $old_require->($path);
   warn("Loaded $path after fork\n");
   return $rv;
};

no warnings 'redefine';
*CORE::GLOBAL::require = $new_require;
```

The solution has the following features:

- Logs modules loaded by `require EXPR`.
- Logs modules loaded by `require BAREWORD`.
- Logs modules loaded by `use BAREWORD`.
- Ignores code loaded by `do EXPR`.
- Ignores modules that fail to load.
- Ignores modules that have already been loaded.
- Works even if `@INC` is manipulated.

The last four were problems experienced by the solution in the OP. I can't find any downsides to this solution.

Comment: One downside: A file without a `package` will place symbols in the wrong namespace. But you shouldn't be passing such a file to `require` in the first place! (You should be using `do`.)

Answer (score 4):

What things are using `do`?  Is simply

```
if $path =~ /\.pm\z/ && !$ignore{$path};
```

good enough to distinguish?

Other options:

Static code analysis with PPI (using or based on [Module::Extract::Use](https://metacpan.org/pod/Module%3a%3aExtract%3a%3aUse)).

Dump %INC to a file upon SIGHUP or some other signal.

Comment: Static analysis won't catch DBD::mysql being loaded by DBI, for example.

Comment: Sending SIGHUP to the forks would be tricky. I'd have to start managing an externally accessible list of the forks.

Comment: This is probably what I'll use, but I'd rather get rid of `%ignore` altogether. What if I ignore XML::SAX (which XML::Simple attempts to load) now, but I install it later? It fails hard. I like my programs to fail safe. Looks like there is no existing solution, so I guess I'll have to publish what I come up with. Any ideas for a name?

Comment: Posted a solution that addresses all the concerns. Thanks anyway.